# Save user mobilenumber - can not be applied to edit text

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am really stuck how to handle the user input with mobile-numbers. I keep get the error "Can not be applied to Edit-text" is there any other way to do this?

XML

```
<EditText
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/mobilnummer"
        android:hint="Mobilnummer"
        android:imeOptions="actionSend"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:background="#ffffffff"
        android:phoneNumber="true"
        android:layout_weight="0.80"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
```

JAVA

```
EditText mobilnummer;
    mobilnummer = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mobilnummer);



  mobilnummer.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            boolean handled = false;
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEND) {
                if (mobilnummer >= 8)     FragmentedUser.SaveMobile(mobilnummer);
                handled = true;
            }
            return handled;
        }
    });
```

Parse code / fragment class

```
  public static void SaveMobile(String mobilnummer) {
    ParseObject fragmentedUser = new ParseObject("FragmentedUser");
    fragmentedUser.put("mobile", mobilnummer);
    fragmentedUser.saveEventually();
    Log.i("Save Mobile", "SaveMobile");
}
```

The only thing that shows in Parse is:android.widget.EditText{236a90fe VFED..CL .F...... 113,0-821,120 #7f0c0059 app:id/mobilnummer}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do some changes. Please have a look.

```
EditText mobilnummer;
        mobilnummer = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mobilnummer);



      mobilnummer.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                boolean handled = false;
                if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEND) {
                    if (mobilnummer.getText().toString().length() >= 8)    
                        FragmentedUser.SaveMobile(mobilnummer.getText().toString());
                    handled = true;
                }
                return handled;
            }
        });
```

Comment: getText method is not valid.

Comment: Please have a look on my Edited answer.

Comment: @datasmurfen Anytime Dude.